# How many streams can a single storm topology handle?

Tags: apache-storm

I have a single topology with two spouts and two bolts. Each spout is acting as a TCP Server. At any instant only one TCP server is taking data. Two TCP servers are not able to take data parallel. Tried same thing with two different topologies each has one spout which acts as TCP server. Two different streams are processed parallel. This whole setup is only on one machine.what could be the problem in first case?